# module EEx is not available

Tags: docker, elixir, elixir-mix

I'm creating an app and when I run it locally things run fine. However, when I run it inside a docker container, during runtime I get the error:

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function EEx.eval_string/2 is undefined (module EEx is not available)

Do I need to specify `:eex` inside the `extra_applicatoins:`? If so can someone point me to the documentation for this? I thought Eex came with Elixir.

This is my `mix.exs` file:

```
# mix.exs

  def application do
    [
      mod: {MyApp.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:tzdata, "~> 1.0.3"},
      {:bamboo, "~> 1.5"}
    ]
  end
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM elixir:1.10 as build

ENV MIX_ENV=prod
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN mix local.hex --force && mix local.rebar --force

ARG LOG_LEVEL=info

RUN mkdir /build

WORKDIR /build

COPY . .

RUN mix deps.get && \
    mix release --path /release && \
    rm -rf /build

WORKDIR /release

ENTRYPOINT ["/release/bin/my_app"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a release, only the [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) core is being packed in (`:elixir` application in terms of OTP.)

Neither `:eex`, nor `:mix`, `:iex`, and some other *extra* libraries are included. Even `:ssl` and `:crypto` available in local development environment [are not included into release by default](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-requirements). The goal is to make it explicit to include anything that might not be needed to avoid bloated releases.

I am not sure it’s explicitly documented somewhere, but you might check for reference [`Phoenix.MixProject`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/mix.exs#L49) that also includes `:eex` application.

For the same reason, any attempt to call `Mix.env/0` (or any other `Mix` function) would fail in release in the same way.